# Fetch groups of a LDAP user spring

Tags: spring, spring-security, ldap, spring-ldap, ldap-query

I used this code to retrieve the group information of an ldap user.

```
        String ldapUri = this.url; 
        Hashtable env = new Hashtable(); 
        env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory"); 
        env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, ldapUri); 
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple"); 
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, this.managerDn); 
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, this.managerPassword); 
        try { 
            LdapContext ctx = new InitialLdapContext(env,null); 
            SearchControls ctls = new SearchControls(); 
            String[] attributes = {"memberOf"}; 
            ctls.setReturningAttributes(attributes); 
            ctls.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE); 
           NamingEnumeration<?> answer = ctx.search("dc=abc,dc=com", "(&(objectclass=user)(sAMAccountName=xxxx))", ctls); 

          **//At this point, I can see the values that I am expecting under entries of answer but hasMoreElements() returns false!** 

            while(answer.hasMoreElements()) { 
                SearchResult rslt = (SearchResult) answer.next(); 
                Attributes attrs = rslt.getAttributes(); 
                String groups = attrs.get("cn").toString(); 
                String [] groupname = groups.split(":"); 
                String userGroup = groupname[1]; 
                System.out.println(attrs.get("cn")); 
            } 
        } 
        catch(Exception e) { 
            e.printStackTrace(); 
        }
```

the answer.hasMoreElements() returns false. But, I can see the values that I am expecting under the entries of answer object while debugging. Can someone please tell me what I'm missing.

If this isn't the right way, how can I get the groups the ldap user is in?

Answer (score 0):

Since sAMAccountName is unique in a Context, you shouldn't expect more than one entry in your result.  You must retrieve the memberOf attribute value to learn about the groups.

Comment: How is this answer helping to solve the problem stated?

Comment: I think the first execution of `hasMoreElements()` works alright, but `attrs.get("cn")` will return null, and `toString()` will bomb.  It's the `memberOf` attribute that should be processed.  Apparently I submitted my answer without finishing it. Sorry.

Comment: Question states that hasMoreElements returns false

Comment: @marabu Probably, you are right about sAMAccountName is unique and it returns only one entry. But the question that arises is when I try to retrieve memberOf attribute, I should also be specifying the user for which I'm trying to get this attribute's value in the filter. That is nothing but sAMAccountName. Do you suggest any alternative way to do this?

Comment: Is it additional attributes you want to retrieve? Just add them: `attributes = {"memberOf", "sAMAccountName"}`

Comment: @marabu: attributes = {"memberOf", "sAMAccountName"} is for fetching values for all the persons in a the given search base and not for a one user, which we are looking for. Again back to the same question: How to retrieve these attribute for one ldap user?

Comment: You don't retrieve the attributes for all entries in the search space, only for the entries in the result set.  This set has size 1 because your filter results in a single user at most, due to the uniqueness of sAMAccountName.

Answer (score 0):

The `hasMoreElements` method of `NamingEnumeration` silently swallows any exceptions that might happen. I'm pretty sure something goes wrong under the hood trying to fetch the results.

Try using the `hasMore` method instead, as this will expose any underlying exceptions that might happen.

Comment: Tried that as well. But didn't work. There aren't any exceptions thrown.